# Swift Protocol: Cannot convert value of type '[x]` to expected argument type of [y]

Tags: swift, generics, swift-protocols

I have the following function:

```
public enum RemoteRecordChange<T: ParsedProtocol> {
   case insert(T)
   case update(T)
   case delete(RemoteRecordID)
}

func processRemoteChanges<T: ParsedProtocol>(_ changes: [RemoteRecordChange<T>], completion: @escaping () -> ()) {
    // To Something
}
```

I am trying to call this function and pass in the parameter:

```
public struct Friend: ParsedProtocol {
  // Has some properties
}

 let friend = Friend()
 // populate properties  friend.username = "aUserName", etc.
```

When calling the function, I am getting an error:

```
 self.processRemoteChanges([friend])
```

Compile Error:

```
`Cannot convert value of type '[Friend]` to expected argument type of `[RemoteRecordChange<..>]'
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong.  I can provide more code, if needed.

Comment: It wants a `[RemoteRecordChange<T>]` and you give it a `[Friend]`. `RemoteRecordChange<T>` is an enum, `Friend` is a struct that implements `ParsedProtocol`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do here does not make sense:

```
self.processRemoteChanges([friend])
```

The method processRemoteChanges` should take a list of "changes" as a parameter. What you are passing in is a list of friends. Does that make sense? No.

According to your enum, a change can be an insert, delete, or update. So choose one of them and pass it to `processRemoteChange`!

If you want to process a remote insert of the friend you just created:

```
// remember the completion handler!
processRemoteChanges([.insert(friend)], completion: {...})
```

If you want to process a remote update of a friend:

```
processRemoteChanges([.update(someFriend)], completion: {...})
```

If you want to process a remote delete of a friend:

```
processRemoteChanges([RemoteRecordChange<Friend>.delete(someID)], completion: {})
```